# Why Images are not showing in bootstrap carousel?

Tags: bootstrap-carousel

I'm using bootstrap carousel. When I open my browser images are not showing in page even though other images which are not in carousel, are not showing. I cant find any error, I'm using visual studio code. [this is a screenshot of that page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMXaP.png) [these are the pictures that I've used in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMcnp.png)
Is there any error that i cant find, please help me-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


   <!-- Required meta tags -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!--Bootstrap css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>
      first web page using bootstrap
    </title>
<!-- Font awesome for brand name-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>

<!-- Nav bar-->

<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: rgb(141, 7, 7); font-size: 25px; font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;"> Stiffy </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Categories
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Beauty</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Health</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lifestyle</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Your Cart</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign In</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!--slideshow starts-->


  <div class="container">
    <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
          <img src="Image\unsplash.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
            <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Chicago</h3>
            <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>New York</h3>
            <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

   <!--slideshow ends-->

<div >

<h3 class="text-center"> For Men </h3>
<img src="Image\unsplash.jpg" width="100px">

</div>

<!-- JQuery,JS, BOOTSTRAP JS-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
[Web page-][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use "../" in each image url of carousel. Like this "../Image/la.jpg" . It is so your index.html page is running from html folder. The current path of your page is html folder so we have to switch to new path with "../" to get one step back to root folder then your path will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your image path insted of mine.
You used bootstrap-carousel but not used classes of carousel
Insted of items you have to used carousel-item.
Same as carousel-control->carousel-control-prev
and for next carousel-control-next

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


 <!-- Required meta tags -->
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

 <!--Bootstrap css-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <title>
  first web page using bootstrap
</title>
<!-- Font awesome for brand name-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Nav bar-->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: rgb(141, 7, 7); font-size: 25px; font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;"> Stiffy </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Categories
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Beauty</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Health</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lifestyle</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Your Cart</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign In</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!--slideshow starts-->


  <div class="container">
    <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/11/25/c285e0144bc93ef6b088c83d7a949ee1-full.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
            <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/11/25/3eb6a87308e5f2ef0a268a68281afc11-full.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Chicago</h3>
            <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/11/25/678c2beaa31d399a502f99c591908e5b-full.jpg" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>New York</h3>
            <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--slideshow ends-->

  <div >

    <h3 class="text-center"> For Men </h3>
    <img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/11/25/678c2beaa31d399a502f99c591908e5b-full.jpg" width="200px">

  </div>

  <!-- JQuery,JS, BOOTSTRAP JS-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not working, still images ain't showing. However thank you for answering.